# How do I batch delete redundant remote git branches?

Tags: git

I have a relatively large collection of remote branches from an old remote repo:

```
$ git branch -r
  guy/feat1
  guy/feat2
  guy/feat3
  guy/feat4
  guy/feat5
  guy/feat6
  guy/feat7
  guy/feat8
  origin/HEAD
  origin/master
```

Is there one command that would remove all `guy` branches?

The repo no longer has `guy` as a remote repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git branch -r | grep guy/ | xargs git branch -d
```

(Assuming the `$` signs aren't actually part of your output...)

Comment: I'm accepting this as the correct answer, as it looks to work. However, I had greater trouble. When running this command, I got messages `error: branch 'guy/feat1' not found.`. Even changing `-d` to `-D` didn't help. Eventually the following answer **did** work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11050880/248220

Comment: A more Git way of iterating like this would be `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' 'refs/remotes/guy/*' | xargs git branch -d`

Answer (score 4):

You can also try (from [`git remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)):

```
git remote --prune guy
```

With:

```
prune
```

> Deletes all stale remote-tracking branches under `<name>`.
>   These stale branches have already been removed from the remote repository referenced by `<name>`, but are still locally available in "remotes/".
>
> With `--dry-run` option, report what branches will be pruned, but do not actually prune them.

See also "[Difference between `git remote prune` and `git branch -d -r`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736728/difference-between-git-remote-prune-and-git-branch-d-r)"

if guy is no longer a valide remote repo, then:

```
git gc --prune=now
```

will clean up those branches (along with some unreferenced commits, so use it with caution)
See more at "[How do you Remove an Invalid Remote Branch Reference from Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072171/how-do-you-remove-an-invalid-remote-branch-reference-from-git)": it is usually more safe to just go with: `git branch -rd guy/badbranch` if possible, but if this doesn't work, then `git gc --prune=now` can also be a solution.

Comment: I looks like this command is not relevant when `guy` is no longer available remotely. Running the command results in: `fatal: 'guy' does not appear to be a git repository.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`. I guess the logic is the command goes to check which branches are no longer at that remote repo.

Comment: I had already run `git gc -prune=now`. It looked like it compressed the repo, but the remote branches remained.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a remote branch you can use
    `git push <remote-repo> :branch-to-delete`
note the colon before branch-to-delete.  Also see [Delete multiple remote branches in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555136/delete-multiple-remote-branches-in-git) ... This shows how to construct a one-liner to delete multiple branches in one go.